# NullPointerException when calling webservice in Weblogic 9.2

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic

I am trying to call a webservice. The client was generated with weblogic's ant task clientgen. But when I use the client, following exception happens:

```
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at com.bea.xbean.xb.xsdschema.SchemaDocument$Factory.parse(SchemaDocument.java:799)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlSchema.parse(WsdlSchema.java:104)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlSchema.parse(WsdlSchema.java:73)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlTypes.parse(WsdlTypes.java:165)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parseChild(WsdlDefinitions.java:480)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlExtensible.parse(WsdlExtensible.java:98)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:428)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlDefinitions.parse(WsdlDefinitions.java:385)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:78)
 at weblogic.wsee.wsdl.WsdlFactory.parse(WsdlFactory.java:65)
 at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.loadWsdlDefinition(ServiceImpl.java:437)
 at weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:108)
  [...]
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
 at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
 at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
 at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
 at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:46)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.bea.xml.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:769)
 at com.bea.xbean.xb.xsdschema.SchemaDocument.<clinit>(SchemaDocument.java:19)
 ... 36 more
```

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: ExceptionInInitializerError Signals that an unexpected exception has occurred in a static initializer. An ExceptionInInitializerError is thrown to indicate that an exception occurred during evaluation of a static initializer or the initializer for a static variable.   do you have the code where this is happening?

Comment: I don't have the code, this happens in a library from the weblogic server (xbean.jar). In the method XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(ClassLoader, String) a
NPE happens, because the first parameter is null. This is all I found out so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a classpath problem. I needed the following jars on my classpath:

- weblogic.jar
- weblogic-container-binding.jar
- xbean.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- webservices.jar
- ant.jar

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way to fix this issue.

Include  under  and add all weblogic server library jars in build.xml
Run setDomainEnv of your domain directory.
Now build webserivces.